# Visual Studio not creating nuget package on build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I have a class library targeting `net471` and I have set up the information in `Properties->Package`. `Generate nuget package on build` is also checked.

I'm also trying to create package manually by right-clicking on the project and selecting `Generate nuget package`.

When I build the project, no package is created.

Am I missing something?

Note: I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.6.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `csproj` and the following section which should be deleted:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Build.Packaging" Version="0.1.227" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Once this is deleted, creating nuget packages works.

Answer (score 1):

try to add (IsPackable) in project reference:
(The main project you want to create a NuGet package for):

`<IsPackable>true</IsPackable>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because we'd made some changes to be able to create temporary packages.

If you have the tag `<PackageVersion>` inside your csproj file, you need to update this value to the new version number (or remove the tag).

The UI doesn't change this tag's value, so you have to go via the XML (VS2019).